# Como pegar o índice comparando duas listas de comprimentos diferentes em Python?

Tags: python, lista, índices, order

Eu tenho duas listas diferentes em dois arquivos CSV.

A primeira lista possui 47843 itens e a segunda 813331, que é a primeira multiplicada por 17.

Eu quero pegar a posição de índice no primeiro, com base no valor do segundo, porque o segundo repete o valor e não tem a mesma ordem como esta:

```
Fisrt
1:   ARS-BFGL-BAC-10919
2:   ARS-BFGL-BAC-10975
3:   ARS-BFGL-BAC-11000
4:   ARS-BFGL-BAC-11003
5:   ARS-BFGL-BAC-11025
6:   ARS-BFGL-BAC-11044
7:   ARS-BFGL-BAC-11193
8:   ARS-BFGL-BAC-11215
9:   ARS-BFGL-BAC-11218
10:  ARS-BFGL-BAC-11276

Second:

1:    ARS-BFGL-BAC-10919
2:    ARS-BFGL-BAC-11003
3:    ARS-BFGL-BAC-10975
4:    ARS-BFGL-BAC-11044
5:    ARS-BFGL-BAC-11000
6:    ARS-BFGL-BAC-10975
7:    ARS-BFGL-BAC-11025
8     ARS-BFGL-BAC-11193
9:    ARS-BFGL-BAC-11044
.
.
.
.
.
.
```

Eu quero esse resultado:

```
{1,4,2,6,3,2,5,7,6....}
```

Comment: já pensou em inserir isso num banco de dados? um SQLite talvez. Um csv de 1M de linhas e sem indexação vai tornar qualquer código, ou lento, ou trabalhoso.

Comment: Eu estou filtrando isso para fazer a inclusão em banco de dados. Porém para fazer a inclusão eu preciso de alguns filtros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como você não forneceu nenhum código, vou inventar aqui de forma simples:

```
lista1 = [
    'ARS-BFGL-BAC-10919',
    'ARS-BFGL-BAC-10975',
    'ARS-BFGL-BAC-11000',
    'ARS-BFGL-BAC-11003',
    'ARS-BFGL-BAC-11025',
    'ARS-BFGL-BAC-11044',
    'ARS-BFGL-BAC-11193',
    'ARS-BFGL-BAC-11215',
    'ARS-BFGL-BAC-11218',
    'ARS-BFGL-BAC-11276',
]
lista2 = [
    'ARS-BFGL-BAC-10919',
    'ARS-BFGL-BAC-11003',
    'ARS-BFGL-BAC-10975',
    'ARS-BFGL-BAC-11044',
    'ARS-BFGL-BAC-11000',
    'ARS-BFGL-BAC-10975',
    'ARS-BFGL-BAC-11025',
    'ARS-BFGL-BAC-11193',
    'ARS-BFGL-BAC-11044',
]
```

A solução mais simples usa indexação normal, pode ser lenta pois ele vai procurar cada elemento de uma lista na outra:

```
>>> print(tuple(lista1.index(elem)+1 for elem in lista2))
(1, 4, 2, 6, 3, 2, 5, 7, 6)
```

Uma outra solução é converter a lista1 em dicionário - a pesquisa em dicionário é quase instantânea então ficaria muito mais rápido:

```
>>> d1 = {item: index for index, item in enumerate(lista1, start=1)}
>>> print(tuple(d1.get(elem) for elem in lista2)
(1, 4, 2, 6, 3, 2, 5, 7, 6)
```

Comment: Problema resolvido :)